# Mapbox Studio for macOS renders GeoTiff into webp with black background - suggestions?

Tags: gdal, mapbox, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles, mapbox-studio

We are converting a 11 MB GeoTiff, [324511630_Descanso_FSTopo.tif](http://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/rastergateway/data/32116/fstopo/324511630_Descanso_FSTopo.tif),
to post to Mapbox, using Mapbox Studio Classic macOS.

The issue is when the Mapbox tileset is posted in Mapbox.com/studio, there is a black border that extends beyond the original GeoTiffs bounding box.

---

Why does a black border appear, and why does it extend past the bbox?

The GeoTiff is on the right hand side of this image.  The gray back ground is the Mapbox style light.

---

[image]

#### Steps to reproduce

- `wget http://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/rastergateway/data/32116/fstopo/324511630_Descanso_FSTopo.tif`
- Mapbox Studio Classic for macOS, `New Source` > `Blank Source` > `New Layer` > `Select 324511630_Descanso_FSTopo.tif`
- Upload to Mapbox `Settings` > `Upload`
- Alternativly, set the zoom to 11-12 for a faster testing process
- The upload is successful with this metadata as reported by Mapbox.com/studio

> ```
> Format | Type   | Size     | Zoom Extent | Bounds
> webp   | raster | 19.28 MB | z11-16      | -180.0,-85.1,180.0,85.1
> ```

#### Notes and Observations

- The GeoTiff is georeferenced and is 7.5 minutes, so the bounding box does not match the GeoTiff bounding box
- The resulting Mapbox tile is webp, which is what we want as we like the size and performance vs png.

#### What we've tried

- As a comparison, We have modified `gdal2tiles.py` to use the WEBP tile driver, and it also has the same black border affect.
- When rendering with gdal2tiles.py with PNG tile driver, there is no issue with the black ground, but the file size in Mapbox.com/studio is > 50 MB.
- from `gdalinfo` we see this data `ColorInterp=Palette` & `Color Table (RGB with 256 entries) 0: 55,53,53,255`
- We are aware of the gdal tools, but we don't know how to set the NODATA given the gdalinfo.
- `gdal_translate -a_nodata 0,0,0,255 in.tif out.tif`  # QGIS only accepts one parameters, so this must be wrong

and we tried this, but produces the same issue

- `gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba 324511630_Descanso_FSTopo.tif rgba.vrt`
- `gdal2tilesp.py -z 11 -f WEBP --srcnodata 0,0,0,255 rgba.vrt`
- `mb-util rgba rgba.mbtiles`
- Upload rgba.maptiles
- We also tried `-expand rgb` instead of `rgba`.  No difference

`gdalinfo 324511630_Descanso_FSTopo.tif`

> ```
> Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
> Files: 324511630_Descanso_FSTopo.tif
>        324511630_Descanso_FSTopo.tif.aux.xml
> Size is 9598, 11366
> Coordinate System is:
> GEOGCS["NAD83",
>     DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
>         SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
>             AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
>         AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
>     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
>     UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
>     AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]]
> Origin = (-116.625000000000000,32.875000000000000)
> Pixel Size = (0.000013023968607,-0.000010998187728)
> Metadata:
>   AREA_OR_POINT=Area
> Image Structure Metadata:
>   COMPRESSION=PACKBITS
>   INTERLEAVE=BAND
> Corner Coordinates:
> Upper Left  (-116.6250000,  32.8750000) (116d37'30.00"W, 32d52'30.00"N)
> Lower Left  (-116.6250000,  32.7499946) (116d37'30.00"W, 32d44'59.98"N)
> Upper Right (-116.4999959,  32.8750000) (116d29'59.99"W, 32d52'30.00"N)
> Lower Right (-116.4999959,  32.7499946) (116d29'59.99"W, 32d44'59.98"N)
> Center      (-116.5624980,  32.8124973) (116d33'44.99"W, 32d48'44.99"N)
> Band 1 Block=9598x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
>   Min=0.000 Max=14.000 
>   Minimum=0.000, Maximum=14.000, Mean=10.365, StdDev=3.715
>   Metadata:
>     STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=14
>     STATISTICS_MEAN=10.365010457425
>     STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
>     STATISTICS_STDDEV=3.7148361607928
>   Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
>     0: 55,53,53,255
>
>     1: 238,51,56,255
>     2: 253,179,56,255
>     3: 187,139,90,255
>     4: 132,119,116,255
>     5: 207,182,159,255
>     6: 187,195,168,255
>     7: 253,202,182,255
>     8: 234,214,190,255
>     9: 200,230,209,255
>    10: 253,222,210,255
>    11: 220,221,223,255
>    12: 0,176,239,255
>    13: 201,217,240,255
>    14: 255,255,255,255
>    15: 0,0,0,255
>    16: 0,0,0,255
>    17: 0,0,0,255
>    <snip>  entries 18 through 254 are identical
>    255: 0,0,0,255
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The black border on the edge of your imagery is the result of the JPG or WebP encoding Mapbox uses as the default image format for raster tiles. JPG images are generally a smaller and faster image format, but we also make PNG images available to support transparency around the edges of your image, however, Mapbox Studio doesn't support PNGs as an image format directly in the editor.

You can use PNG images with both Mapbox.js and Mapbox GL JS, though the process is a bit different for each.

For Mapbox.js projects:

```
L.mapbox.tileLayer('map.id', {
  format: 'png256'
}).addTo(map);
```

If you are using Mapbox GL JS, you will need to make some manual edits to your JSON file to point to the raster source as a png layer. See [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/danswick/c19fec2e92e00967458d) for details. Also, GL JS will use WebP if the browser supports it (only Chrome), otherwise it will use JPEG.

If you are still seeing the black border, you may need ensure the TIFF image was properly exported with the NODATA values. To do this, use GDAL and the following command:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 input.tif output.tif`
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @geografa.  This helps.  We found the right mix of WEBP compressions and how to pack it into Mapbox servers — https://github.com/roblabs/gdal2tilesp/tree/WEBP-png

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.gdal.org/frmt_webp.html:

`The WEBP driver supports 3 bands (RGB) images. It also supports 4 band
(RGBA) starting with GDAL 1.10 and libwebp 0.1.4.`

Can you verify the GDAL and libwebp versions you are using?

Comment: I am using `GDAL 1.11.4, released 2016/01/25` on macOS from KyngChaos.  I'm not sure how to find the WEBP version.