# Why does MapBox serve trasparent pixels only below a certain zoom level?

Tags: raster, gdal, mapbox, web-service, gdal2tiles

We're using MapBox to serve a raster tileset.

At low zoom levels the transparent pixels are seethrough:

[image]

When you zoom in though it goes black (we've added oppacity):

[image]

Questions:

- Why is this
- How to stop it with MapBox?
- Will it work out-of-the-box with `gdal2tiles`?
- Any other references about best practice for serving partially transparent raster tiles?

To reproduce the behaviour: http://npct0.vs.mythic-beasts.com/msoa/?r=isle-of-wight

Context: https://www.jtlu.org/index.php/jtlu/article/view/862

Answer (score 1):

I found the Mapbox layer that you mentioned [here](https://github.com/npct/pct-shiny/blob/6afa3c318117cd5a61726bf288c8449873fbe653/regions_www/msoa/server.R#L577).  And it is listed as servering `PNG` on the Mapbox servers.

`https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/alexfrost.0oaowqxv/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

But if you navigate to the Mapbox Tileset, https://www.mapbox.com/studio/tilesets/alexfrost.0oaowqxv, using your Mapbox login credentials, then you see that your format is `webp`.  Which is fine, but could be contributing to your problem.  Screen capture below as you need a Mapbox account to view that link.

See this thread for further discussion [Mapbox Studio for macOS renders GeoTiff into webp with black background - suggestions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208362/mapbox-studio-for-macos-renders-geotiff-into-webp-with-black-background-sugges)

[image]